# Type Expected error

Tags: c#, asp.net, typeerror

I have a type expected error on a { , but i am not missing any off.

I really don't know what the problem is and i have looked about for solutions, i know i have a lot of commenting out but that is just code that wont work for some different reason.

```
    namespace Antiques
    {
        public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page, //ISaleManagerUI
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        public void LoadData()
        {
            try
            {
                Application.Lock();
                UpdateListbox();
                Application.UnLock();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Error: Not found, must save first";
            }
        }

        protected void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        public void AddData()
        {
            var response = base.Response;
            response.Redirect("Default.aspx", true);
        }

        protected void btnAddBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddData();
        }

        public void UpdateListbox()
        {
        }

        protected void lb1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateListbox();
        }


        protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (lb1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                ListItem mySelectedItem = (from ListItem li in lb1.Items where li.Selected == true select li).First();
                lb1.Items.Remove(mySelectedItem);
            }
        }

        protected void lb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void SaveData()
        {
        }

        protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveData();
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: You commented out the interface but left the comma before it.  It's looking for an interface to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the comma at the end of the class declaration:

```
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page,
```

It's expecting another type which you haven't provided.

Comment: thank you so very much sir, as you can see i am not very good at this